# Table text extends past the right margin

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| c | |c |}
\hline
Feature & Elaboration \\ [3ex]
\hline\hline
\\Budget Friendly & The system inputs financial budget of user in it's system, and provides a list of hotels that can be accessed with that budget. \\ [10ex]
\\Interactivity & While using the system, the barrier between machine and user is eradicated to the maximum capability. A user should feel as he/she is talking to a representative of a hotel. \\ [10ex]
\\Data Handling & The data of a user is recorded by the system. It can be easily accessed in the system. \\ [10ex]

\hline
\end{tabular}
```

The text that I've written is not completely coming in the table. What mistake have I done, or what should be corrected?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Thanks for showing us what's happening, and what you've tried.  Please provide a complete minimal working example, though, with code including `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`, so we can just copy-paste and run it to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the correct column type for your second column. You need text wrapping, so you can use `p{<width>}` type column or preferably `X` type which calculates the remaining space automatically, use `tabularx` for the latter. Also, instead of adding manual vspace like `\\ [3ex]`, just increase the array stretch by `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}`, for example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c||X|}
\hline
Feature         & Elaboration \\ \hline\hline
Budget Friendly & The system inputs financial budget of user in it's system, and provides a list of hotels that can be accessed with that budget. \\ 
Interactivity   & While using the system, the barrier between machine and user is eradicated to the maximum capability. A user should feel as he/she is talking to a representative of a hotel. \\
Data Handling   & The data of a user is recorded by the system. It can be easily accessed in the system.\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: It worked. Thankyou so much!

Comment: @user1234556 If the answer solve you problem, it is polite to accept the answer by clicking the green tick to the left of the number to the top left of the answer. Also upvote, if you have enough reputation.